# Cursor is passing through emoji

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When I set maxLines to null in TextField then for the emojis below the first line the cursor passes through the center if you tap on the center of emoji.

[image]

And when I add new emoji the following happens:

[image]

The emoji with cursor passing through it breaks into invalid characters.

Here's the code of TextField:

```
TextEditingController _commentTextController = TextEditingController();


TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  cursorWidth: 1,
  autocorrect: false,
  cursorColor: Colors.black,
  controller: _commentTextController,
  maxLines: null,
  autofocus: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Your comment...",
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
)
```

And when I try to extract and set new text in TextField with the following code:

```
String currentComment = _commentTextController.text;

String newCommentText = currentComment + ""

setState(() {
  _commentTextController = TextEditingController(text: newCommentText);
});
```

The TextField vanishes with the following log:

```
I/flutter (27958): Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): string is not well-formed UTF-16
I/flutter (27958): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'alphabeticBaseline' was called on null.
I/flutter (27958): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getBoxesForRange' was called on null.
I/flutter (27958): Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
```

I have added the gif below to show how buggy the emoji behavior is for lines below the first line.

[image]

In short, just set maxLines to null in TextField or TextFormField to see this effect.

**Edit: CupertinoTextField doesn't have this bug so I guess I will try that until this is fixed**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed by the Flutter team.
https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/10063